# How do I use EntityQueue's API

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to tie EntityQueue permissions into Organic Groups, similar to what was done with Smartqueues for Organic Groups (https://www.drupal.org/project/smartqueue_og ) but EntityQueue's API does not contain things like hook_subqueue_access().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_subqueue_access().
 */
function smartqueue_og_subqueue_access($subqueue, $account, $queue) {
  if (og_user_access($subqueue->reference, 'administer queues', $account)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}`
```

Do I need to patch EntityQueue to contain the API functions I need? Or are the API functions available through CTools (or EntityAPI) that EntityQueue was built on? And if so, how do I hook those APIs?

Comment: `hook_subqueue_access` is a hook any module can implement by calling it, as the code you pasted above does.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but hook_subqueue_access is defined in the Nodequeue's api, and since I want to use Entityqueue, not Nodequeue, I'm looking for hook_entityqueue_subqueue_access or similar.